# Is there a vertical line test correlate in 3 space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For single output functions in the x,y plane the vertical line test is used to check if a given curve is a valid function. Is there a correlate for this in the x,y,z plane, for parametric equations, equations of planes etc.?

Comment: If z=f(x,y), then we can use a vertical plane (the x-y plane) test, I guess, to see if it's an implicit relationship.

Comment: Wouldn't the xy plane be horizontal? Also I think it might still be a vertical line test, where the line is at values (x,y) extending in the z direction where there should be only one value of z corresponding to each x,y value? Or maybe it would be an xz plane, and a yz plane test?

Comment: Think about what it means for a set of ordered pairs in $\mathbb R^2$ to be a function. That constraint leads directly to the vertical line test. Now extend that reasoning to ordered triples $(x,y,z)$.